# Series Convergence, Did I do this correctly

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}$$

I did this:
Limit comparison test with $\frac{1}{n}$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{n^{1+\frac{1}{n}}}}{ \frac{1}{n}}$$
simplify
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{-2-\frac{1}{n}}$$
I then concluded that because $\frac{1}{n}$ in the exponent approaches 0 as $n$ approaches $\infty$ then the whole limit converges to a finite positive number. So I said that because $1/n$ diverges, by LCT the original series also diverges

Can someone confirm?

Comment: Should be $n^{-1/n}$, not $n^{-2-1/n}$.

Comment: I see what I did wrong..